# xcode/swift/cocoa - Shifted subview

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa

1-  i speak little english (sorry) (google translate is my friend !)

2 - i’m a beginner in swift/poo/low level programming … (jumping from bash to swift)

3 - I have a problem !! -> in my main window i have some custom views including custom subviews. All works fine except that in the custom view at the left bottom, the subview seems to be shifted (at the bottom left to).

I have not enough reputation to post images but it seems the subview is at the offset (20.20) …

(Fortunately all the rest works fine, I click on the button, I select a file and dates are displayed in the right subview)

Answer (score -1):

Auto-answering : i've set it programmatically :

```
    showBalanceViewControler.view.frame = ShowBalanceSubView.frame
    showBalanceViewControler.view.frame.offset(dx: -20, dy: -20)
```

But i still don't understand why previous lines are necessary ...